# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. Any Ideas?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I keep getting a this error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tmp_ms_x__3214EC0750F0A8B2'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Table'. The duplicate key value is ().

The statement has been terminated.'

I don't know what I did wrong, anyone have a clue?

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace FBLA_Project_1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\LUCY\Documents\testerfile.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           

        }
          
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText= "insert into [Table] (Id, Name, EmployeeID, Sunday) values('" + textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox4.Text+"','"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+"')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            disp_data();
            MessageBox.Show("Data has been put in succefully ");
        }

        public void disp_data()
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from table ";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Line 33 is around where I get my error. It's really annoying after tinkering around for hours and being in the same place.

Comment: Dont concat to make SQL.  Use SQL parameters always.  And  use the correct tags for your question: that is not VB.NET.  Also dont ignore the duplicates offered when typing your title

Answer (score 0):

In your insertquery  the number of the values provided (4)  don't match the number of the columns defined during  table creation 
then you should explicitally assign the column name (eg: assuming you columns name  are col1, col2, col3, col4)

```
 cmd.CommandText="insert into [Table] (col1, col2, col3, col4) 
 values('"+textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox4.Text+"','"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+"')";
```

Comment: I did what you said, however, I ran into more errors.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tmp_ms_x__3214EC0750F0A8B2'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Table'. The duplicate key value is ().

Here is the edited bit of code: cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText= "insert into [Table] (Id, Name, EmployeeID, Sunday) values('" + textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox4.Text+"','"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+"')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: the error mean that the insert now work correctly and  you are  trying to insert a duplicated  value  .. 

You should check the value you have in your table  and the value you are trying to insert  ..